# How to explicitly define `this` as `any` in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm writing higher-order functions in TS and I need to use `this`. I don't know what `this` refers to until it's used. However, I get:

```
'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
```

The functions look something like:

```
function foo(fn) {
  return function(...args) {
    const ctx = this as any;
    ...
    return fn.apply(ctx, args);
  };
}
```

I know I can turn off `noImplicitThis` or use `@ts-ignore`. I tried the following:

```
const ctx: any = this;

const ctx = this as any;

const ctx: any = this as any;
```

None of these worked. Is there a way to fix this without disabling rules?

Comment: You need to specify the type of fn.

Comment: You might be looking for `function(this: any, ...args) {}`? However, explicit `any` often isn't much better than implicit `any`, I'd rather recommend to make `foo` generic and introduce a type parameter for it.

Comment: I don't understand why `function(this: any, ...args) {}` would be a good option, every consumer of the function would have to know to pass in the context (which is usually `window` anyway)?

Comment: No, they are fake parameters. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters

Comment: I see, thanks! So even if I make `foo` generic, I still can't do `const ctx = this as T`. I'd prefer not using the fake parameter, since it'll be confusing to anyone new to TS. I guess `@ts-ignore` is the best way for now

Comment: @LeoJiang No, really not. Instead of putting an `@ts-ignore` comment above that line, just use the proper solution and put a comment with a link to the docs for that syntax above that line for TS newbies.